# How to save mounted files from docker to any directory with python docker sdk?

Tags: python, docker

here is the case:

I need to save files from mounted directory, for example, in my Desktop. How can I do that?

```
import os, stat
import shutil

import docker

client = docker.from_env()

mounts = [docker.types.Mount(source ="/absolute/path/to/source/folder/" + docker_image_id, target="/target_folder", type="volume")]
ok = client.containers.run(image="image_name", detach=True, remove=True, mounts = mounts, name=ip)
```

This code makes an error:

```
docker.errors.APIError: 
400 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/create?name=TestContainer1: 
Bad Request ("create /home/cv/Desktop/archive_TestContainer1: "/home/cv/Desktop/archive_TestContainer1" 
includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. 
If you intended to pass a host directory, use **absolute path**")
```

Comment: For a bind mount, do you need `Mount(type='bind')` instead of `type='volume'`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Idk is it a stupid implementation. I made one more docker container what is provides an access to file storage in /usr/lib/docker/volumes/*volumename* and put every file in this "controller".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).